# ServerSelectionTimeoutError on connecting AWS Document DB through AWS Lambda function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, pymongo, aws-documentdb

I've been trying to connect to AWS Document DB through a python script written in AWS Lambda function.

Code is:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    create_mongo_connection()

def create_mongo_connection():
    try :   
        conn = pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://<username>:<password>@test-document-db-exportify.cluster-c9puxz9rzs0a.ap-south-1.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017/?ssl=true&ssl_ca_certs=rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem&replicaSet=rs0&readPreference=secondaryPreferred&retryWrites=false')
        db = conn['exportifydb']
        docs = db['constants'].find({})
        for doc in docs:
            print(doc)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

However, it raises:

```
    raise ServerSelectionTimeoutError(                                                                                                                                  
    pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: test-document-db-exportify.cluster- 
    c9puxz9rzs0a.ap-south-1.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017: timed out, Timeout: 30s, Topology 
    Description: <TopologyDescription id: 611f576267e03bfd2fcb0b3c, topology_type: 
    ReplicaSetNoPrimary, servers: [<ServerDescription ('test-document-db-exportify.cluster- 
    c9puxz9rzs0a.ap-south-1.docdb.amazonaws.com', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, 
    error=NetworkTimeout('test-document-db-exportify.cluster-c9puxz9rzs0a.ap-south- 
    1.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017: timed out')>]>
```

However, I can connect to the samedb and access query results using shell and Robo3T

Comment: Probably a firewall issue.

Comment: Yes, got solved after configuring VPC and security group.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the TLS was enabled on parameter group of the cluster in DocumentDB settings. I see you are passing in the ssl true and make sure your certificate is authenticating with configured certificate on the cluster. Hopefully that should resolve the issue.